# Creating an interface that excludes a single key, where all other dynamic keys are of the same Type

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I'm still learning all the intricate details of the TypeScript type system and was wondering if someone could help me with this interface design question.

I am looking to create an interface in TypeScript where one or more object keys are of a generic type and all remaining keys must be of the same type. I've played around with a mixture of conditional types and `never` type unions and have not come up with a working solution.

```
type Command = () => void;
type ViewState = {[key: string]: any};

export interface ViewModel<T extends ViewState> {
  viewState: T;
  // The following line is what does not work
  [key: Omit<string, 'viewState']: Command;
}

// The result I am aiming for,
interface LabelState {
  label: string;
}

interface LabelModel<LabelState> {
  viewState: LabelState;
  updateLabel: Command;
}

interface MenuState {
  menuItems: string[];
}

interface MenuModel<MenuState> {
  viewState: MenuState;
  openMenu: Command;
  closeMenu: Command;
};
```

I understand that this is not necessary, however, it would be neat to know that all methods were a `Command`. It feels like this should be possible, is there anyone out there that knows definitively if it is or is not achievable? If so, what I am missing?

Comment: So you basically want to check that `MenuModel` and `LabelModel` only define `Command` properties except for `viewState` ?

Comment: Exactly, I know that it's not a huge deal from a design perspective and wouldn't be done in most languages. It seems like something that TypeScripts type system could support though.

Comment: I don't understand this example completely; is `MenuState` supposed to be a concrete type or a type parameter?  You're using the name both ways for some reason.  Should `MenuModel` be concrete or generic?  Does `LabelState` enter into this example anywhere?  It's not being used.

Comment: `MenuState` is a generic state that a `MenuModel`s `viewState` would take the form of. Likely, it would be an object which is all you need to implement a TypeScript interface. The `MenuModel` would likely be a class. Nothing in this example is a `concrete` implementation yet, as that wouldn't affect the outcome of the example.

Comment: When I said "concrete" I just mean non-generic. I am still confused about the purpose of the *interfaces* named `LabelState` and `MenuState`, when they are not used anywhere.  The fact that `LabelModel` and `MenuModel` have type parameters with those same names adds to the confusion because they are unrelated.

Comment: I mean, is there any reason why I shouldn't look at the code like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMoF4oAoCU2AfFAG5wCW6A3AFCiRQBqFEA7gMrDLDQ4DeAbQDWEEAC4oAZ2AAnCqgDmAXUloQAXzq0FvWQDNkAY2gAZZACMIAGy49o-WlCjXLNyTPlK6G2jtR6hiZQ5lbWALJw6DYAPKYkjs6krJzcvJKmdM4ArmDo9qHusIgoGD5+uhAGxtDhEKjZdrxQiVAI9dkAkrwIUh5yCoqCyuX+gTVQdQ2R0dYx4QlOZClNEJLhWVBwkKhT2ZLwSGg0S0bWcFIQewclxz50QA)?  It's the same as yours.  What is the intended relationship or use of the interfaces named `LabelState` and `MenuState`?

Comment: I am very confused by your definition of "unused" in example nothing is "used", however, everything is used by the interface design. As for you code example, it's missing the general-purpose type `ViewModel<T extends ViewState>` which is the entire point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way to approach this:

```
type ViewModel<T> = {
  [K in "viewState" | keyof T]: K extends "viewState" ? ViewState : Command
};
```

The `ViewModel` type is generic not in the type of state, but in the intended extension of `ViewModel` itself.  Examples might make more sense here:

```
interface LabelModel<S> extends ViewModel<LabelModel<S>> {
  viewState: S;
  updateLabel: Command;
}

interface MenuModel<S> extends ViewModel<MenuModel<S>> {
  viewState: S;
  openMenu: Command;
  closeMenu: Command;
}
```

Those are the same as your `LabelModel` and `MenuModel` types, but the `extends ViewModel<...>` enforces the constraint you're talking about.  This `interface Foo extends ViewModel<Foo>` construct is called [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification), but basically means that you can make an interface refer to its own type.  TypeScript actually has a feature called "[polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)" which lets you do this without an extra type parameter, but it can't be used inside mapped types the way I'm doing it... oh well.

Anyway, the `ViewModel<T>` basically takes a type `T`, and makes a new type where all the properties of `T` whose keys are not `"viewState"` have a `Command` value type, and also there is a `"viewState"` property of the `ViewState` type.  So by saying `interface X extends ViewModel<X>`, we're saying that `X` must be assignable to something where the only non-`Command` property is `viewState`.

Let's see a violation of this and what happens:

```
interface BadModel extends ViewModel<BadModel> { // error!
  viewState: ViewState,
  notACommand: string
} // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Command'.
```

So the constraint is enforced.  I hope that meets your needs or at least gives you an idea.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMoF4oAoCU2AfFAG5wCW6A3AFCiRQBqFEA7gMrDLDQ4DeUANoBrCCABcUAM7AAThVQBzALpS0IKAF869cNBbsAsnHQQANgB4AKiQG0owgNJRFUAESlWnbr3dQAHygxEDgAMyhrNSgXCAAPXgxpDy92Lh4IfwB+Zm903igpeCQ0dFodWlpFXjkw5ABjaAAZZAAjCxMzKw4SeMT0ZMM2TotLFvbzEe6iEn4HMjzfCCkOOkcAVzB0DPGLIsQUDDotSuqIWoboIwhUdanLHqg+m4Hc41NR69v7ntn51J8GRWaygcEgqC+632JSO83q5jg0ggkOhhxo5VOqBqdUaUAAQsh0FMngkXoNvPcCUSPuZZlAAPT0p5yORwOQAQn+iyBb0BvAANPNUHBgABBYpoqSyBTKcoMpnWfRQADk0sUSmVrmSwuAUGQ0mkFCUqDa5mgwDgUAY0GVEtKyoAdLQgA)

Comment: That's neat I never thought to try a union type in the key definition.

Comment: I don't think the `keyof T` is right. It's just any string.

Comment: There's no way to represent as a concrete type "all strings except for `"viewState"`, so you have to approach the type you want indirectly, as a constraint.  So if your desired type is generic `T`, then you talk about `keyof T` instead of `string`, and you can say "all `keyof T` except for `"viewState"`".